# I try to get an instance of the WorkManager and get a RuntimeException! Is there a walkaround?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, runtimeexception, android-workmanager

here is the relevant stacktrace:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
```

Crash
TCT (Alcatel) 5056D
Android 6.0 (SDK 23)
48.aab
2 hours ago

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:2887)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900 (ActivityThread.java:150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1427)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService.onCreate (SystemJobService.java:2)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:2877)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900 (ActivityThread.java:150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1427)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What could the walkaround this issue? Is there another way to initialize the WorkManager instance? I'm using

```
private fun getWorkManager(): WorkManager =
        try {
            WorkManager.getInstance(App.context)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            sleep(100)
            getWorkManager()
        }
```

Comment: From [the source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/background/systemjob/SystemJobService.java;l=1?q=SystemJobService.java&sq=), that exception would get thrown if "`WorkManagerInitializer` has been disabled but `WorkManager` is not manually initialized in `Application#onCreate`". If your code is working elsewhere, that suggests that this device is somehow interfering with `WorkManagerInitializer`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found only one walkaround - I had to disable backups im my app manifest to avoid this exception due to its appearance during the data backup process